# I want to display 2-March-2019 is like '02-Mar-2K19'

Tags: date, date-formatting

I want to display date year like 2K19

In Php or wordpress

```
Example 08 OKT 2019 to 08 OKT 2K19
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
strftime("%d %b 2K%y");
```

Obviously this won't work for dates prior to 1 January 2000.